# Does the preimage of closed set coincides with all the closed sets on $X$ ? If not, under which conditions does it hold?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$.

Does the set of the (closed) preimages of closed sets in $Y$ coincides with the set of the closed in $X$ ?

More formally, let $V$ be any closed set in $Y$. Does $\{f^{-1}(V) \}$ coincide with the set of all closed sets in $X$ ?

If not, under which conditions on $f$ is the coincidence true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a topological space with $\mathcal G_Y = \{Y\backslash T: T\in \mathcal T\}$ denoting its set of closed subsets (because of the way the question is posed, I'll  treat a topological space as a set equipped with a collection of closed sets, i.e. a collection of subsets closed under finite union and arbitrary intersection). If $X$ is a set and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a function, then $\{f^{-1}(V): V \in \mathcal G_Y\}$ is a topology on $X$, and this is the weakest (in the sense of having as few closed sets) topology for which $f$ is continuous.

Now suppose that $f\colon X \to Y$ is continuous with $\mathcal G_X$ denoting the set of closed subsets of $X$, and suppose that $f$ has the property that any closed subset $Z$ of $X$ can be written as $f^{-1}(V)$ for some closed subset $V$ of $Y$.  This condition still holds if we replace $Y$ with its image, where we equip $\text{im}(f)$ with the subspace topology -- that is, closed subsets of $\text{im}(f)$ are sets of the form $V\cap \text{im}(f)$, so we may as well assume $f$ is surjective. But then if $Z\in \mathcal G_X$ has $Z=f^{-1}(V)$, we must have $V=f(Z)$, so that the subset $Z$ of $Y$ is determined by $Z$. Thus the condition implies that $f$ is a closed map, that is, $f$ takes closed sets to closed sets, and we must have $Z = f^{-1}(f(Z))$, that is, $f$ induces an injective map from the closed sets of $X$ to the closed sets of $Y$. If $X$ is T_1 say, so that points are closed sets, then this implies that $f\colon X \to Y$ is injective, i.e. $f$ is an embedding of the topological space $X$ into the topological space $Y$.

If $X$ is not T_1, then this need not be the case (e.g. the two-point set $X=\{0,1\}$ with closed sets $\{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$ mapping to a one-point set has the required property, but $T_1$ is a pretty weak assumption, so one would expect most spaces one comes across to satisfy it!

Comment: In the first paragraph of your answer, did you mean "If $X$ is a set and $f$ is a continuous function" ?

Comment: No, if you start with $Y$ a topological space and $X$ any set, then a function $f\colon X \to Y$ lets you "pull back" the topology $\mathcal G_Y$ on $Y$ to a topology $f^{-1}(\mathcal G_Y)$ on $X$, making $X$ into a topological space. If $X$ already has a topology, then the condition that $f$ is continuous is that the topology on $X$ contains the topology $f^{-1}(\mathcal G_Y)$. I hope that clarifies things a bit!

Comment: Just another question: in your second paragraph, did you mean "can be written as $f^{−1}(V)$ for some *closed* subset $V$ of $Y$" ? Because in my question, I've required $V$ to be a closed of $Y$.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- I've edited the post to correct that, thanks for spotting the mistake!

Comment: That's absolutely no problem, thanks to you for such a detailed and nice answer :)